# how to connect rapidminer to mongodb

Tags: java, json, xml, mongodb, rapidminer

I converted a xml document to json and store it in mongodb (in java),there are ceveral Document nested in the json,then I connected rapidminer to the collection  but when i visualise the content of the collection I one row and multiple columns.
for example, i have this json :

```
{
     ' lat ' : 48.8566667,
     ' lng ' : 2.3509871  ,
     ' i '   : {
          ' id '       : ' id_element ' ,
          ' ville '    : ' Paris ',
          ' pays '     : ' France ',
          ' nbResult ' :  5
     }
 }
```

and when I visualte it with rapidminer (json to data) I get 
a table with one row and multiple columns, each column contains for example : 
lat or i.id, i.ville... i don't get the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know rapidminer. But if it does not support a specialized view for nested objects, this is the common way, to display a nested document in a 2-dimensional table.

The nesting level is transformed to the dot `.` in the column name to show what attributes belong to the same nested document (`i.id`, `i.ville` belong to `i`). It's called `flatten document`, because the nested documents are reduced to first level attributes containing the information of the nesting in the attribute name.

Comment: thank you for your reply, you are right, but I don't know if it's my insertion that is false , so I visualized  my collection in robomongo and  it is very consistent, maybe I have to insert one line by line in my collection , but the problem is that I converted my xml to json without knowing its contents